# Как автоматизировать счёт модулей целых чисел в списке?

Tags: python

я пробовал складывать только с помощью метода pop без модулей

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]
b = a.pop(2)
c = a.pop(3)
d = b + c 
print(d)
```

Comment: Что значит "счет целых чисел"? В вашем списке все числа целые. Сумма через `sum(a)` не подходит?

Comment: я хочу сложить числа  с 1 элемента и до конца с помощью цикла это возможно?

Comment: причём мне нужно сложить их модули

Comment: Научитесь формулировать точное условие задачи

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets,по вашему s=0; for x in a: s+=x` это сумма модулей?Это ведь сложение не отрицательных чисел

Comment: `sum(abs(x) for x in a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько понял задачу:

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]

b = 0
for digit in a:
    b += abs(digit)

print(b)
```

Если не морочиться с циклом то:

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]
b = sum(abs(i) for i in a)
print(b)
```

Или так:

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]
b = sum(map(abs, a))
print(b)
```

Comment: Или так: `b = sum([abs(i) for i in a])` -> `b = sum(abs(i) for i in a)`

Comment: А это не дублирование ответа, а подсказка вам :)

Comment: Квадратных скобок нет. Разве не заметно?

Comment: Все понял. Согласен. Спасибо. Не сразу сообразил что за стрелка между выражениями )))

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]    
acc = 0
for i in a:
    acc += abs(i)
print(acc)
```

или

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]    
b = reduce(add, map(abs, a))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант через [list.pop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
a = [-1, 2, -1, 3, 3, -5]

b = 0
while a:
    b += abs(a.pop())

print(b)  # 15
```